# Completed Event Handler for Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I want to know when some parallel tasks are completed.

I'm using this code to make between 1500 and 2000 small WebClient.DownloadString with a 10 seconds HttpRequest Timeout on a website:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    Parallel.ForEach<string>(myKeywords, new ParallelOptions 
    { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, getKey));
```

Sometimes, a query fails, so that there are exceptions and the function never finish, and the UI refresh inside each getKey function sometimes seems to be called twice, so I cannot get an accurate idea about how many tasks are completed. I'm calculating: Number of UI refresh calls / total number of keywords, and get a result between 100% and 250%, and I never know when task are completed. I search in a lot of SO discussion but none was a direct method or a method that suits my needs. So I guess Framework 4.0 doesn't provides any Tasks.AllCompleted Event Handler or similar workaround?

Should I run my Parallel.Foreach in one other thread instead of my UI thread then add it?

```
myTasks.WaitAll
```

[EDIT]

A temporary solution was to copy my list of string in a ArrayList, then removing one by one each item from the list at the beginning of each query. Whenever the function worked well or not, I know when all items have been processed.

Comment: 1. You want which items are successfuly finished and which  are failed

2. You want to get continuous progress, like 5%, 10%, ... 100%
....... If you require either of above, you need to use own sync mechanism, which may slow down overall processing (due to synchronization)..............If you only need to know which are failed, your temp. solution is suited(even though not the elegent one)

Comment: I required either, but it worked at least for % purpose since removing one by one the item from the song list allows to calculate (total items - remaining item) / total items. Anyway, if a download fail, it's up to me to handle it with a retry loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Parallel.ForEach` is no different than other loops when it comes to handling exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460695%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  If an exception is thrown, then it is going to stop processing of the loop.  This is probably why you're seeing variances in the percentages (I assume you might be processing the count as you're processing the loop).

Also, you don't really need [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) becuase the asynchronous calls that you're making on the [`WebClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) are going to block waiting on [IO completion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (the network responses), they are not computationally bound (`Parallel.ForEach` is much better when you are computationally bound).

That said, you should first translate your calls to `WebClient` to use [`Task<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx).  Translating the [event-based asynchronous pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx) to the [task-based asynchronous pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) is simple with the use of the [`TaskCompletionSource<TResult>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx).

Assuming that you have a sequence of [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) instances that are produced as a result of your calls to `getKey`, you can create a function to do this:

```
static Task<String> DownloadStringAsync(Uri uri)
{
    // Create a WebClient
    var wc = new WebClient();

    // Set up your web client.

    // Create the TaskCompletionSource.
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    // Set the event handler on the web client.
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) => {
        // Dispose of the WebClient when done.
        using (wc)
        {
            // Set the task completion source based on the
            // event.
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                // Set cancellation.
                tcs.SetCancelled();
                return;
            }

            // Exception?
            if (e.Error != null)
            { 
                // Set exception.
                tcs.SetException(e.Error);
                return;
            }

            // Set result.
            tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
        };

    // Return the task.
    return tcs.Task;
};
```

Note, the above can be optimized to use *one* `WebClient`, that is left as an exercise for you (assuming your tests show you need it).

From there, you can get a sequence of `Task<string>`:

```
// Gotten from myKeywords
IEnumerable<Uri> uris = ...;

// The tasks.
Task<string>[] tasks = uris.Select(DownloadStringAsync).ToArray();
```

Note that you *must* call the [`ToArray` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) in order for the tasks to start running.  This is to get around [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).  You don't have to call `ToArray`, but you must call something which will enumerate through the entire list and cause the tasks to start running.

Once you have these `Task<string>` instances, you can wait on them all to complete by calling the [`ContinueWhenAll<TAntecedentResult>` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362141.aspx) on the [`TaskFactory` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.aspx), like so:

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, a => { }).Wait();
```

When this is done, you can cycle through the `tasks` array and look at the [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception.aspx)  and/or [`Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468.aspx) properties to check to see what the exception or result was.

If you are updating a user interface, then you should look at intercepting the call to [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx), namely, you should call the [`ContinueWith<TNewResult>` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321326.aspx) on the `Task<TResult>` to perform an operation *when that download is complete*, like so:

```
// The tasks.
Task<string>[] tasks = uris.
    Select(DownloadStringAsync).
    // Select receives a Task<T> here, continue that.
    Select(t => t.ContinueWith(t2 => {
        // Do something here: 
        //   - increment a count
        //   - fire an event
        //   - update the UI
        // Note that you have to take care of synchronization here, so
        // make sure to synchronize access to a count, or serialize calls
        // to the UI thread appropriately with a SynchronizationContext.
        ...

        // Return the result, this ensures that you'll have a Task<string>
        // waiting.
        return t2;
    })).
    ToArray();
```

This will allow you to update things as they happen.  Note that in the above case, if you call `Select` again, you might want to check the state of `t2` and fire some other events, depending on what you want your error handling mechanism to be.